# The named parameter 'email is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

I've a problem with this kind of bug and I hope someone can please tell me how to fix it.

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_form/model/login_model.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool hidePassword = true;
  LoginRequestModel requestModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestModel = new LoginRequestModel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 85, horizontal: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            blurRadius: 20)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Form(
                      key: globalFormKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          new TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input,
                            validator: (input) =>
                                !(input?.contains("@") ?? false)
                                    ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                    : null,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Email Address",
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .accentColor
                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                              )),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          new TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            onSaved: (input) => requestModel.password = input,
                            validator: (input) => (input != null &&
                                    input.length < 3)
                                ? "Password should be more than < 3 characters"
                                : null,
                            obscureText: hidePassword,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Password",
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .accentColor
                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                              )),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(hidePassword
                                    ? Icons.visibility_off
                                    : Icons.visibility),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Login",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (validateAndSave()) {
                                  print(requestModel.toJson());
                                }
                              },
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 12,
                                    horizontal: 80,
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  shape: StadiumBorder())),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

this is my Loginmodel.dart code

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  final String status;
  final String message;
  final String kid;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String password;

  LoginResponseModel({
    required this.status, 
    required this.message, 
    required this.kid, 
    required this.uid, 
    required this.email,
    required this.password});


  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
        status: json["status"] as String? ?? "",
        message: json["message"] as String? ?? "",
        kid: json["kid"] as String? ?? "",
        uid: json["uid"] as String? ?? "",
        email: json["email"] as String? ?? "",
        password: json["password"] as String? ?? "",
      );
  }
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;

  LoginRequestModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'email': email.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
    };
    return map;
  }
}
```

The error:

> The Error On LoginRequestModel requestModel; says " Non Nullable Instance field 'requestModel' must be initialized.
>
> Then Error message on requestModel = new LoginRequestModel() says The Named Parameter 'email is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
>
> And Last On OnSaved = input says "A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'string'."

I really appreciate the answer you gave

Answer (score 1):

> The Error On LoginRequestModel requestModel; says " Non Nullable Instance field 'requestModel' must be initialized.

You need to change:

```
LoginRequestModel requestModel;
```

Into the following since you are first setting the value in `initState` and therefore the variable are not going to be given a value right away then the object is created:

```
late LoginRequestModel requestModel;
```

> Then Error message on requestModel = new LoginRequestModel() says The
> Named Parameter 'email is required, but there's no corresponding
> argument.

I don't know the content of the class `LoginRequestModel` but I would guess it has a named parameter `email` which is required to be specified when calling the `LoginRequestModel` constructor.

> And Last On OnSaved = input says "A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'string'."

Again, I don't know your `LoginRequestModel` class but I would guess the `email` field is not nullable. That is a problem since `onSave` expects a method with the signature:

```
void FormFieldSetter<T>(
    T? newValue
)
```

So your code here does not take into account that `input` is a nullable variable:

```
onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input
```

Since some of your problems is related to issues with Dart null-safety I will recommend you to read: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: So i need to show my LoginRequestModel code in here?

Comment: @HandikaPramudyaPutra Yes, I can see in your `LoginRequestModel` does not allow either `email` or `password` to have the value `null` (since they both have the type `String` and not `String?`). If you don't want `null`, you need to handle the case where `input` in `onSaved` can be `null` (since the type for `input` is `String?`). You can e.g. change the line to: `onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input ?? ''` if you want to set `email` to the empty string in case of `input` being `null`. Alternative you can change `email` to be `String?` or don't change `email` in case of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

One by One,

The first one, you defined `LoginRequestModel requestModel` as non-nullable by default means that this variable is declared normally cannot be null. [more detail](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety) You could just change `LoginRequestModel requestModel;` to `LoginRequestModel requestModel= new LoginRequestModel();`, instead of giving a value in `initState`. It looks like

```
  LoginRequestModel requestModel = new LoginRequestModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // requestModel = new LoginRequestModel();
  }
```

Or use `late` (It is expensive)

Second one, I think in `LoginRequestModel` will lool like this `LoginRequestModel({@required this.email})`. You can choose to remove `@required` or give a empty value.

Last one, since `requestModel.password` and `requestModel.email` is non-nullable, it should like `onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input!;`

Comment: Someone said need to put required on this.email if i remove those my code cant be run

Comment: Maybe you can give it an empty value or really pass a real data. I don’t sure. It depends on your LoginRequestModel

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix your problem.
In order to solve the error

1. assign the value of `requestModel` at the time of declaring it instead of in `initState`.
2. pass empty string as arguments to `LoginRequestModel` because `email` and `password` are required field.
3. write `input!` instead of `input` to indicate that  `input` is not null

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_form/model/login_model.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool hidePassword = true;

  LoginRequestModel requestModel = new LoginRequestModel('','');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 85, horizontal: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            blurRadius: 20)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Form(
                      key: globalFormKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          new TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input!,
                            validator: (input) =>
                                !(input?.contains("@") ?? false)
                                    ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                    : null,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Email Address",
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .accentColor
                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                              )),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          new TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            onSaved: (input) => requestModel.password = input!,
                            validator: (input) => (input != null &&
                                    input.length < 3)
                                ? "Password should be more than < 3 characters"
                                : null,
                            obscureText: hidePassword,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Password",
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .accentColor
                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                              )),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(hidePassword
                                    ? Icons.visibility_off
                                    : Icons.visibility),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Login",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (validateAndSave()) {
                                  print(requestModel.toJson());
                                }
                              },
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 12,
                                    horizontal: 80,
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  shape: StadiumBorder())),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```